# What commutative algebra book should I read next?

Tags: commutative-algebra

I have read *Introduction* by Atiyah & Macdonald, but not finished all exercises, and also studied a little algebraic geometry (affine varieties and projective varieties).

Recently I am reading GTM150 but found it kind of hard and confusing (such as some new definitions,) so what should I read next? Go on studying GTM150 or *Commutative Ring Theory* by Matsumura or some other choices? Please give me some advice, thanks advance!

Comment: As usual, the question is: To what purpose are you doing this reading?

Comment: I am not sure people remember GTMs by their number. What book is it? The author of *Commutative RingTheory* is *Matsumura*, by the way.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews well, I am trying to study algebraic geometry and the teacher told me to study commutative algebra first.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon sorry to make the mistake

Comment: @PedroTamaroff the book is *commutative algebra with a view toward algebraic geometry* by Eisenbud, and thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: @user365833 That's a very good read, and quite long. You have lots of paths to pick there. I'd say give it time.

Comment: I would prefer Matsumura's (any of his two books) as first choice, or as second Grothendieck's EGA, $0.\S4-0.\S23$ (included at the beginning of EGA I, III and IV).